# ComboBox and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have ProjectID and Name in data table. cbProjects is ComboBox.

Here is a piece of code.

```
ProjectEntities projectE = new ProjectEntities();
cbProjects.ItemsSource = projectE.Projects;
cbProjects.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
```

Can I get information about ProjectID of selected Name in ComboBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cbProjects.SelectedValuePath = "ProjectID"
```

Then you can get the id of selected item via `cbProjects.SelectedValue`.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void cbProjects_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;

    var item = cb.SelectedItem as Project;
    int projectID = item.ProjectID;

}
```

or

```
var item = cbProjects.SelectedItem as Project;
int projectID = item.ProjectID;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using VS 2010 with EF 4, here's the code which is working for me:

```
//load entities to the combo box
ProjectEntities projectE = new ProjectEntities();
var pdata = projectE.Projects;
cbProjects.DataSource = pdata; //cbProjects.ItemsSource
cbProjects.DisplayMember = "Name"; //cbProjects.DisplayMemberPath

//get selected value
var item = cbProjects.SelectedItem as Project;
int projectID = item.ProjectID;
```

Comment: Exaclty! Needed to get entity object from Combobox item. Thanks!